# how do i get a structure in c++ from python?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

My C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct FirstStructure
{
public:
    int first_int;
    int second_int;
};

struct SecondStructure
{
public:
    int third_int;
    FirstStructure ft;
};

int test_structure(SecondStructure ss)
{
    int sum = ss.ft.first_int + ss.ft.second_int + ss.third_int;
    return sum;
}

extern "C"
{
    int test(SecondStructure ss)
    {
        return test_structure(ss);
    }
}
```

And I compile the cpp file use this command "g++ -fPIC -shared -o array.so array.cpp".
Then I call the file array.so use python,my python program as these:

```
#coding=utf-8

import ctypes
from ctypes import *


class FirstStructure(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("first_int", c_int),
        ("second_int", c_int)
    ]


class SecondStructure(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("third_int", c_int),
        ("ft", FirstStructure)
    ]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fs = FirstStructure(1, 2)
    ss = SecondStructure(3, fs)
    print ss.ft.first_int
    lib = ctypes.CDLL("./array.so")
    print lib.test(ss)
```

When I run the python program,the console show an error, the error is "segmentation fault".I read the documentation from the url "https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html",how to fix the bug.

Comment: Although on Windows, I copied your code as is with the exception of adding `__declspec(dllexport)` to the `test` function and loading a  .dll instead of .so and it worked perfectly, returning `1` and `6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok,I got it,modified code as these:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
struct FirstStructure
{
public:
    int first_int;
    int second_int;
};

struct SecondStructure
{
public:
    int third_int;
    FirstStructure ft;
};

int test_structure(SecondStructure *ss)
{
    int sum = ss->ft.first_int + ss->ft.second_int + ss->third_int;
    return sum;
}
    int test(SecondStructure *ss)
    {
        return test_structure(ss);
    }
}
```

and then,I fixed the bug.

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare a function's argument and return types in python, in order to be able to call it properly.

So, insert the following before calling the `test` function:

```
lib.test.argtypes = [SecondStructure]
lib.test.restype = ctypes.c_int
```

Things should work then, as far as I can see...

As long as the amount of C-to-python interfaces remains "small" (whatever that is), I think `ctypes` is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are intending to design communication medium between C++ and python then I would suggest go for combination zmq and google protocol buffers.

where proto buf would serve for serialization/deserialization and zmq for communication medium.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at Boost.python

https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/SimpleExample

It will allow you to compile python modules from C++ and define how the python is allowed to access the c++ code in an easy to understand fashion